# Bootstrap 3 collapse block - direction of showing

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need advice on an adjustment or plugin to make the "collapseExample" always open downwards after clicking.

`<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">Link with href</a>`

`<div class="collapse" id="collapseExample"><div class="well">...</div></div>`

Thank you for the advice

[image]

Comment: isnt collapse always downwards?

Comment: No. If you scroll below and click on "Zobrazit více ....", the content will open up at https://www.amtek.cz/vykonove-polovodice/ . It is necessary to scroll the page a bit

Comment: Hi, just wanted to ask if my answer below did solve the issue for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place the collapsible section below the button that toggles it. Put the `div` with id `c782` below the `div`, that is currently below it - `<div class="btn-group-2 btn-group-bs bg-group--bg-ico">` (it is the div with the buttons).

Comment: Your solution is good. Unpacking always takes place downwards. But because the expanded content is long, then the close button is missing at the bottom. Therefore, the HTML is arranged in such a way that the button is always below the expanded block.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want the content to expand downwards, but the toggle button should be below the expanded content?

Comment: Yes, you understand very well.